# Calculation in a loop in R

Tags: r, loops

Consider the following data:

```
library(Benchmarking)

x <- c(2, 3, 8)
y <- c(1, 5, 10)
k <- 25
d <- data.frame(x,y,k)
x <- c(5, 2, 3, 4)
y <- c(3, 5, 9, 10)
k <- 30
d2 <- data.frame(x,y,k)

d3 <- replicate(3, rbind(d, d2[sample(seq_len(nrow(d2)), 3), , drop=FALSE]), simplify = FALSE)
```

So now I have a list of 3 `data.frame`. For each of these 3 `data.frame` I want to perform the following calculation:

```
e1 <- with(subset(d3[[1]], k == 25), dea(d3[[1]]$x, d3[[1]]$y, XREF = x, YREF = y))
e2 <- with(subset(d3[[1]], k == 30), dea(d3[[1]]$x, d3[[1]]$y, XREF = x, YREF = y))
we1 <- weighted.mean(eff(e1), d3[[1]]$y)
we2 <- weighted.mean(eff(e2), d3[[1]]$y)
va <- we2/we1
```

But instead of using that code three times, where I change `[[1]]` to `[[2]]` and `[[3]]`, can I instead use a loop, where it does the calculation for all 3 `data.frame` and create a new `data.frame` where it list `va` for the three calculations?

Comment: Create it as a function and loop through the `list` of datasets and apply the function i.e. `lapply(d3, f1)`

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Is it possible that you can provide som more code? Not sure how to do it?

Answer (score 0):

We create a function and then loop through the `list` and apply the function

```
f1 <- function(dat) {
   d1 <- subset(dat, k == 25)
   e1 <- with(d1, dea(dat$x, dat$y, XREF = x, YREF = y))
   d2 <- subset(dat, k == 30)
   e2 <- with(d2, dea(dat$x, dat$y, XREF = x, YREF = y))
   we1 <- weighted.mean(eff(e1), dat$y)
   we2 <- weighted.mean(eff(e2), dat$y)
   we2/we1

}

sapply(d3, f1)
```